# How to sort result set on basis of a value?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am writing some queries for search engine having 5 parameters.

Its a basic search but the problem is I want to sort the order of the results on the basis of a selection like we do in the search engines with the relevance functionality.

I am using codeigniter as the framework and Active Records Library for the Database operations.

Thanks

J

Comment: Could you please gice us more detaisl on the querry and what you get as a result?

Comment: This question is far to vague to give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to define a relevance function, then you need to compute the relevance of each result, then you need to sort by the result of that computation. It's theoretically simple, the hard part is coming up with a good relevance function. We can't do that for you based on a vague description of some search engine.

Comment: I have searched out the way to handle that request to. Its the easiest to handle while using CODEIGNITER as a framework. I used ActiveRecords helper to achieve the result.